# Windows 7 can't login when LAN cable plugged in

Tags: windows-7, networking, passwords, lan

If I login to any user account in my PC and type the password for any users the password will be accepted but when I plug out the LAN cable from my PC(if cable were plugged in).

It shows username or password incorrect.
What is the problem?
Can anyone explain?
thanks.
 My system information shown in image below -

[image]

Comment: i'm sure my password is right,but i can't login when LAN cable plugged in(it shows password incorrect). if cable were plugged out no problem..

Comment: Why does it show you are part of a domain? If its saying your password is incorrect its likely because, your part of a domain, and thus the password has indeed expired.

Comment: when i change the password,the problem still occurred...

Answer (score 3):

That looks to me like it thinks it's on a domain, yet I'm guessing it isn't - so when it goes looking for authority to log you on it doesn't find it.

To the left of the screen you posted there should be "Advanced System Settings" Click that, then the Computer Name tab.

Click Change & swap it from a Domain to a Workgroup [the name is really unimportant unless you are on a corporate network, so let it use WORKGROUP]

Reboot will be required.